# using --load flag to the builder in compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, buildx

Is it possible to send the '--load' flag to the docker-container driver using docker-compose?

it's a pain to send the built images to the registry, then to download them again each time I do a change.

For information, I use the docker-container driver to build multi architecture containers.